# Enter/Space key doesn't work on only some buttons in JAWS + IE

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

Having an issue just in JAWS 18 + IE 11 (it works fine in Chrome, Firefox and with NVDA and with just the keyboard, no screen reader).

This works:

```
<ul class="user-options">
    <li>
        <button id="fa_lo" tabindex="0" class="step-one-button" aria-label="Question one header question one answer one">
            <span>question one answer one</span>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button id="fa_ci" tabindex="0" class="step-one-button" aria-label="Question one header question one answer two">
            <span>question one answer two</span>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button id="fa_in" tabindex="0" class="step-one-button" aria-label="Question one header question one answer three">
            <span>question one answer three</span>
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

but this doesn't:

```
<ul class="user-options">
    <li>
        <button id="h_no" tabindex="0" aria-label="Question Two Header Question two answer no" class="step-two-button">
            <span>Question two answer no</span>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button id="h_yes" tabindex="0" aria-label="Question Two Header Question two answer yes" class="step-two-button">
            <span>Question two answer yes</span>
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can tab-key to the second set of buttons but it doesn't announce the text and pressing enter or space doesn't do anything. It doesn't make sense the first set would work fine with no problems but not the second set when I can't see any differences.

It will work with CTRL + enter or shift + enter, but that's not acceptable to our accessibility team. It should work with just the enter or space key with no modifier key.

Comment: I just tried your code example and enter/space works on the second set of buttons using JAWS (2018) and IE (11).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div role="application">
<ul class="user-options">
    <li>
        <button id="h_no" tabindex="0" aria-label="Question Two Header Question two answer no" class="step-two-button">
            <span>Question two answer no</span>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button id="h_yes" tabindex="0" aria-label="Question Two Header Question two answer yes" class="step-two-button">
            <span>Question two answer yes</span>
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: please do not use `role="application"`.  that's a last resort solution if you have an element that requires direct keyboard input, such as single character shortcut keys